# f:setPropertyActionListener can not set the property

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i am trying to set value of my backingbeans property via

```
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{customer}"
                            target="#{customersViewBean.selectedCustomer}" />
```

but it does not set the value.it is surprising that i have initialized this property in the class but when i pushed the command link, it is set to null and gives null pointer exception.do you have any idea what is wrong?

```
    <p:dataList id="datalist5"
                value="#{customersViewBean.filteredPositionCustomer}"
                rendered="#{customersViewBean.positionaGoreListe}"
                var="customer">
                <p:column style="padding-bottom:1px!important;">
                    <p:commandLink id="commandLink"

                        action="#{customersViewBean.getCustomerDetail}">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{customer}"
                            target="#{customersViewBean.selectedCustomer}" />
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="false"
                            target="#{customersViewBean.comingFromOpportunityDetailToAddressList}" />

                        <h3>#{customer.name}</h3>

                    </p:commandLink>

                </p:column>
            </p:dataList>
```

Comment: Why do you set false to comingFromOpportunityDetailToAddressList? What is type of this variable? Can you try with removing second setPropertyActionListener line?

Comment: i tried deleting the second parameter but result same

Comment: Post your backing bean code too please